# $(...).highcharts is not a function despite correct order of files

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My first assumption (and from searching SO) was that I'd put the files in the wrong order.

After much experimentation it seems this isn't the case - although it did fix another issue I had, so a good result all the same.

The head contains:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highstock-all.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/charting.js"></script>
```

Charting.js is:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // create the chart
        $('#chartcontainer').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title: {
                text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                buttons : [{
                    type : 'hour',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1h'
                }, {
                    type : 'day',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1D'
                }, {
                    type : 'all',
                    count : 1,
                    text : 'All'
                }],
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled : false
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                type: 'candlestick',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
});
```

There are no issues being displayed in the console other than that highcharts is not a function. The same happens if I just use:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

rather than linking the local copies.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highcharts-all.js is not part of offered framework from Highcharts.

See this forum post.
http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/highstock-all-t32340/

Also it's not listed in their file service.
http://code.highcharts.com/

Second way is working perfectly. See in their samples

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how that happened, because I tried that before. Must have skipped over something when I did it..

Knew it would be something derpy.


    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script>//yourstuff</script>
For anyone reading this in the future, it is